# django.core.mail.EmailMessageクラスでメールを送信すると、タイトルが文字化けする対策を教えてください

Tags: python3, django

django.core.mail.EmailMessageを、利用して、WEBアプリ内に問い合わせフォームの実装を行っております。

ローカルの環境で開発しており、受信するメールの内容は、コンソールに表示させています。

その際に、フォーム内のタイトルの項目で入力した内容を、メールのタイトルで受信するように設定していますが、タイトルが文字化けしてしまいます。

メール本文は、文字化けせずに表示されます。
また、コンソールの１行目に【Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"】と表示があるのでUTF-8の設定になっているとみていますが、どうして文字化けするかわかりません。

解決の方法について、ご教授いただきないでしょうか？
実行環境と関係ファイルのコードは以下の内容です。

実行環境
Mac: mojave 10.14.6
Python: 3.7.5
Django: 3.0.0

メール受信内容のコンソール内容(４行目が文字化け箇所）

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: =?utf-8?b?44GK5ZWP44GE5ZCI44KP44GbIHt9?=
From: admin@example.com
To: test@example.com
Cc: sample@example.com
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 04:24:29 -0000
Message-ID: <157733426951.17628.14334668042684224451@ApplenoMacBook-Pro.local>

送信者名: テストユーザー
メールアドレス: sample@example.com
メッセージ:
テスト
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


class InquiryForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='お名前', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='メールアドレス')
    title = forms.CharField(label='タイトル', max_length=30)
    message = forms.CharField(label='メッセージ', widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control col-9'
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'お名前をここに入力してください。'

        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control col-11'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'メールアドレスをここに入力してください。'

        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control col-11'
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'タイトルをここに入力してください。'

        self.fields['message'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control col-12'
        self.fields['message'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'メッセージをここに入力してください。'

    def send_email(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        message = self.cleaned_data['message']

        subject = 'お問い合わせ {}'.format(title)

        message = '送信者名: {0}\nメールアドレス: {1}\nメッセージ:\n{2}'.format(name, email, message)
        from_email = 'admin@example.com'
        to_list = [
            'test@example.com'
        ]
        cc_list = [
            email
        ]

        message = EmailMessage(subject=subject, body=message, from_email=from_email, to=to_list, cc=cc_list)
        message.send()
```

views.py

```
import logging

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from .forms import InquiryForm

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class InquiryView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'inquiry.html'
    form_class = InquiryForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:welcome')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        logger.info('Inquiry sent by {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['name']))
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

inquiry.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}お問い合わせ{% endblock %}

{% block active_inquiry %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<body class="login">
<div>
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signup"></a>
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signin"></a>
    <div class="login_wrapper">
        <div class="animate form login_form">
            <section class="login_content">
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

                    {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                            <strong>{{ field.label_tag }}</strong>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            {{ field }}
                            {{ field.errors }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <div class="offset-sm-4 col-sm-8">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">送信</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: [これ](https://sendgrid.kke.co.jp/blog/?p=10958)を読んでみて下さい。

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA リンクを貼る際は「リンク先に何が書いてあるのか」(通常はページタイトル) をテキストに設定しておくと、より親切だと思います。 / 参考: [リンクの文脈を提示する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - "`リンクの前後に文脈がわかる記述を入れ、そのリンクが何で、どうしてそこにあるのかがわかるようにしておきます。`"

Comment: @cubick そうですね。了解です

Comment: @ Kohei TAMURAさん、コメントありがとうございます。
紹介したもらったサイトにまさに、同じエラーの事が書いてありますね。

対策として【=?文字セット?エンコード方式?エンコード後の文字列?=】という形式で指定するとなりますが、私のプログラムの場合だと、form.pyの【subject = 'お問い合わせ {}'.format(title)】を【subject = '=?UTF-8?B?お問い合わせ {}.format(title)?='】というように書き換えるという対応の仕方で正しいでしょうか？

Comment: いえ、そもそも文字化けしていないですよね。なぜか`.format(title)`が効いてないみたいですけど。質問本文にある「メール受信内容のコンソール内容」のメールを[Online MIME Headers Decoder](https://dogmamix.com/MimeHeadersDecoder/)でデコードしてみて下さい。「お問い合わせ {}」というタイトルのメールが表示されるはずです。実際に、このメールを受信して適当なメーラーで開いてみると、タイトルは文字化けされていないことが分かると思います。

Comment: @ Kohei TAMURAさん、コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおりそもそも文字化けしていませんでした。さきほど自分で回答を載せましたが、コンソール表示だと、日本語で表示されないのが、デフォルトの設定のようです。本番環境で試すと、日本語で表示されました

Comment: 文字化けしているのではなく、RFC 2047の仕様に従って、デコードされているということです（念のため）。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答となりますが、下記のサイトに関係する内容がありましたので、今回の質問の対応について紹介させてもらいます。
参考サイト）https://speakerdeck.com/thinkami/djangocongress-jp-2019-talk

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

の設定で、コンソールにメールの内容を表示する場合は、件名が日本語にならないのが、デフォルトの設定のようです。

私の場合も、最初の質問で載せた、ファイルとコードのまま、本番環境へデプロイを行い、問い合わせフォームより、メールを送信すると日本語で表示されました。

それでも、ローカルの環境で件名を日本語で見たい場合は、console.EmailBackendを拡張(write_message() メソッドをオーバーライド)する必要がありました。

myapp.email_backends.py

```
class ReadableSubjectEmailBackend(console.EmailBackend):
def write_message(self, message):
from email.header import decode_header
subject = message.message().get('Subject')
decoded_tuple = decode_header(subject)
# => [('Django', None)] # MIMEヘッダエンコーディングなし
# => [(b'\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\xa3\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb4', 'utf-8')]
if decoded_tuple[0][1] is not None:
readable_subject = decoded_tuple[0][0].decode(
decoded_tuple[0][1])
self.stream.write(f'\nSubject (日本語表示): {readable_subject}\n')
super().write_message(message
```

settengs.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'myapp.email_backends.ReadableSubjectEmailBackend'
```

コンソール表示

```
Subject (日本語表示): ジャンゴ
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Subject: =?utf-8?b?44K444Oj44Oz44K0?=
```